# xbindkeys/xkb map ctrl shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb, xbindkeys

I have installed colemakwide(xkb) and would like to keep shortcut like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> etc. The goal is that all <kbd>ctrl</kbd> shortcut behave like QWERTY which I did in windows/klc by have the original vk for the keys. I used the following script to map <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>:

```
"xdotool key --delay 0 --clearmodifiers ctrl+c" 
Release + m:0x4 + c:54
```

which works fine to copy/paste and to send sigint in the terminal.

But when I try to map two keys the script stops working of some reason.

```
"xdotool key --delay 0 --clearmodifiers ctrl+x"
Release + m:0x4 + c:53
"xdotool key --delay 0 --clearmodifiers ctrl+c"
Release + m:0x4 + c:54
```

Any thoughts on how to fix that or how to map the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> behavior in xkb directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough privilege to edit files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/` folder,
there is a way to do it without `xdotool`.
You need to create a new `type` where `Ctrl` moves to `level3` a bit like `AltGr`, and set every alphabetical key to this type.

I answered with more details on [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609605/xkb-transparently-map-modifier-level/610330#610330), it looks similar to what you need.