# XKB Transparently map modifier level

Tags: xkb

I use a layout which is not QWERTY for first and second level.

```
    key <AC06> {
        type= "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC",
        symbols[Group1]= [               m,               M,        Left,        Home ]
    };
    key <AB01> {
        type= "ALPHABETIC",
        symbols[Group1]= [               x,               X ]
    };
```

I would like any key combination which has Ctrl in it (left Ctrl, or left and right ctrl) to change the layout back to QWERTY for the keypress.

So if I type `Ctrl+<AB01>` I would like to get `Ctrl+z`, and if I type `ctrl+shift+<AB01>` I would like `Ctrl+shift+z`. `Ctrl+<AC06>` = `Ctrl+h`, etc

Is something like this possible with xkb?

Comment: It's possible. How many non-qwerty levels do you need?

Answer (score 1):

There are two important folders:

- `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` is where your non-Qwerty layout is located on most distros.
- `/usr/share/X11/xkb/types` is for modifiers (like `Ctrl` or `Shift`) behavior.

It has 4 official levels, compatible with `Ctrl`, `Shift` and `Lock` (aka `CapsLock`).
I added this code in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/types/level5` :

```
type "QWERTY_CONTROL" {
    modifiers = Shift+Control+Lock;
    map[None] = Level1;
    map[Shift] = Level2;
    map[Control] = Level3;
    map[Shift+Control] = Level4;
    preserve[Control] = Control;
    preserve[Shift+Control] = Control;
    map[Lock] = Level2;
    map[Lock+Shift] = Level1;
    map[Lock+Control] = Level4;
    map[Lock+Shift+Control] = Level3;
    preserve[Lock+Control] = Control;
    preserve[Lock+Shift+Control] = Shift+Control;
    level_name[Level1] = "Base";
    level_name[Level2] = "Shift";
    level_name[Level3] = "Alt Base";
    level_name[Level4] = "Shift Alt";
};
```

I added it on line 2, after `partial default xkb_types "default" {`.
And now you should use the type name `QWERTY_CONTROL` instead of `FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC`.

Here is the code for keyboard layout. I added mine on `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/oo`:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "half_qwerty" {
    augment "level5"
        name[Group1]="french ergodox compat";

    key.type[Group1] = "QWERTY_CONTROL";

    key <LatA> {[egrave, Egrave, a,A]};
    key <LatS> {[eacute, Eacute, s,S]};
    key <LatD> {[p, P, d,D]};
    key <LatF> {[apostrophe, degree, f,F]};

};
```

Then run `setxkbmap oo -variant half_qwerty` to try it.
You should get `è` (`egrave`), `é` (`eacute`), `p` and `'` on the middle row.
If you use them with `Ctrl`, it's still `a`, `s`, `d` and `f`.

Note: I tested it on several softwares

- It works on: MPV, Dolphin, Gedit, LibreOffice, Firefox, ST+ZSH, ST+NeoVim and Rofi.
- It doesn't work well on Chromium.